# Squid proxy server loads only Google sites

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

I have just installed Squid proxy server on a CentOS 7 system and everything went smooth but the proxy loads only the Google sites like YouTube, Google Search, and so on...

when I visit another site it shows "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" on my browser.

My squid.conf file is the basic one but I commented all the "http_access" lines and kept only "http_access allow all"

Also I commented "cache_dir" and added "cache deny all" because I want Squid to run as a proxy only without caching.

Also I have set "dns_v4_first on" and "dns_nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1"

Please note that HTTP sites work fine but not HTTPS (except Google sites)

I dont know what is causing the issue but I know that only HTTP work especially that the browser resolves the HTTPS sites and it redirects from http:/ to https:// but then it shows "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Note that I have Squid 3.5

Edit: The access.log file shows "TCP_MISS" on the non-working sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your ISP is blocking the Squid HTTPS `CONNECT` tunnel. See https://superuser.com/a/529061/936854

I found a solution for CentOS 7 but unfortunately you will have to leave Squid and use [3proxy](https://github.com/z3APA3A/3proxy) because it uses alternatives of the CONNECT tunnel.

The solution is:

Step 1: Install the following (the most important step because Development Tools contains packages that helps in bypassing the ISP block)

```
yum -y update

yum -y install epel-release net-tools firewalld

yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Step 2: Install 3proxy server. You can use [this installer](https://github.com/h1777/3proxy-rhel) for CentOS 7.

Step 3: Since your ISP allows only the Google traffic for proxies, then make sure to include the following in your 3proxy configuration file to use the Google DNS servers:

```
nserver 8.8.8.8
nserver 8.8.4.4
nscache 65536
```

Comment: Yes i noticed that its my isp blocking proxies especially after trying different proxy servers and they had the same problem.